Alembic migration in Docker returns error that table not exists
I have tried to create a migration for my postgres db, but have faced with error in Docker (locally it works).
Steps to reproduce:

Locally init alembic async migrations
Create a new revision
In update function in version file wrote:

def upgrade() -> None:
    op.add_column(Product.__tablename__, sa.Column("status", sa.String(255)))



run docker compose up -d --build
docker compose exec container_name alembic upgrade head

And then got an error:
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.asyncpg.ProgrammingError) <class 'asyncpg.exceptions.UndefinedTableError'>: relation "products" does not exist
[SQL: ALTER TABLE orders ADD COLUMN state VARCHAR(255)]

In my postgres container this table exists.
Maybe you know where is a mistake?

Try to change the way you specifying table name:
def upgrade() -> None:
    op.add_column('products',sa.Column('status', sa.String(255)))

Best Practices for Alembic Migrations that migrationn scripts should be self contained and not rely on your application models. in Docker environment database schema might not be fully initialized and that why this error occurs
